# OPA350 behavior at high frequencies

Tags: operational-amplifier

I just recently bought a OPA350 OP-AMP due to its fast recovery speed that I need for my application (Precision Rectifier), it just arrived today and I went to go test the circuit. However weir behavior is starting to surface at high frequencies...but this time it's the Vpk-pk.

Datasheet: [OPA350](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos099d/sbos099d.pdf)

---

[image: Output at 584 Hz]

Frequencies of (100Hz-10kHz)

---

[image: Output at 21 kHz]

Frequencies of (20kHz)

---

As you can see the \$Vpk-pk\$ took a beating at 20kHz and I thought this was due to the bandwidth of the OP AMP, however it's stated to be 30MHz. It also gets much noisier as well.

GBW EQUATION:

\$F_c=\frac{30MHz}{1}=30MHz\$

so the flatness should decade 6dB/sec after 30MHz ish, but why is it doing it around 20kHz?

SLEW RATE EQUATION:

\$SR = 20kHz*2*\pi\$
\$SR = 0.127V/uS\$

The OP AMP is rated for 22V/uS

Schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFYjXQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you checked the slew rate?  That's often a gotcha

Comment: Its more than enough :/ its faster than my old OP AMP which was slower.. the Slew rate is at 22V/uS should be more than enough.

Comment: I don't see much rectification going on there. Where are you measuring it? Also, use 1:1 probe setting to reduce the noise from the oscilloscope.

Comment: Try putting a 1 kohm load after the diode to 0 volts.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany sorry I didnt put the cap in. This is just the output signal. The problem I have isnt the rectification but the output signal attenuating really hard.

Comment: @Andyaka Nvm For some reason my signal much more cleaner now, but the Vpkpk still took a dive its around 1V now oppose to 2.84V. This is without load.

Comment: ALRIGHT sorry, here is what i learned. The op amp is working perfectly its my input that is attenuate not the output of the op amp.

Comment: My MacBook and iPhone is attenuating it’s signals at higher frequencies . Ahaha thought it was my op amp sorry guys.

Comment: It's worth noting that your negative excursion of the input signal is taking the input below gnd by more than recommended. I'd also replace the In4148 with a much lower Vf diode to get more signal output capability. This may help: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01353A.pdf